# Messaging feature disabled by default for a Twilio number

Tags: twilio

I created an evaluation free account. My objective was to test the service and check if it adapts to our needs. I read that message sending is available in evaluation free accounts.
I validated a Spanish phone number. And in the country support URL I saw Spain as supported country for domestic messaging.
I got into the account settings and enabled Spain as messaging country.

But, when I go to manage numbers page, messaging is disabled.

I reviewed docs and faq with no success. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Understood with Twilio support.
There are two kind of numbers: national and local.
In Spain, just local numbers can be used but those are not available in the evaluation free account.